# Display full sized image on <img> hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an `<img>` in an MVC 4 Razor Display Template, and I'd like to display a tooltip containing the full sized image when the user hovers over the image.

HTML:

```
<img height="50" width="50" src="@Model.ImageString" />
```

`@Model.ImageString` contains an image data string, which looks like this:

```
"data:image/*;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(file.Data)
```

If you couldn't guess, `file.Data` is a `byte[]`.

How can I display a full-sized tooltip upon hovering the `<img>`?

Comment: Google "display image on rollover" and you'll be presented with numbers of ways of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/bGn96/

This is along the lines of what Shan Robertson is suggesting.

```
var $tooltip = $('#fullsize');

$('img').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var img = this,
        $img = $(img),
        offset = $img.offset();

    $tooltip
    .css({
        'top': offset.top,
        'left': offset.left
    })
    .append($img.clone())
    .removeClass('hidden');
});

$tooltip.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $tooltip.empty().addClass('hidden');
});
```

A library that provides the desired functionality can be found here: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/

Comment: If you take a look at their main.js, they are binding to the links but there's no reason you couldn't modify it so that the binding is directly associated with the image element.

Comment: @ArrayKnight Since your answer was similar to Shan's answer, I +1'd his answer. +1 to you also for acknowledging his contribution.

Answer (score 3):

```
var Controls = {
init: function () {
    var imgLink = document.getElementById('thumb');

    imgLink.addEventListener('mouseover', Controls.mouseOverListener, false );
    imgLink.addEventListener('mouseout', Controls.mouseOutListener, false );

},

mouseOverListener: function ( event ) {
    Controls.displayTooltip ( this );
},

mouseOutListener: function ( event ) {
    Controls.hideTooltip ( this );
},

displayTooltip: function ( imgLink ) {
    var tooltip = document.createElement ( "div" );
    var fullImg = document.createElement ( "img" );

    fullImg.src = imgLink.src;
    tooltip.appendChild ( fullImg );
    tooltip.className = "imgTooltip";

    tooltip.style.top =  "60px";

    imgLink._tooltip = tooltip;
    Controls._tooltip = tooltip;
    imgLink.parentNode.appendChild ( tooltip );

    imgLink.addEventListener ( "mousemove", Controls.followMouse, false);
},

hideTooltip : function ( imgLink ) {
    imgLink.parentNode.removeChild ( imgLink._tooltip );
    imgLink._tooltip = null;
    Controls._tooltip = null;
},

mouseX: function ( event ) {
    if ( !event ) event = window.event;
    if ( event.pageX ) return event.pageX;
    else if ( event.clientX ) 
        return event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?
                                document.documentElement.scrollLeft :                 
                                document.body.scrollLeft); 
    else return 0;
},

mouseY: function ( event ) {
    if (!event) event = window.event; 
    if (event.pageY) return event.pageY; 
    else if (event.clientY) 
        return event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ?     
                                document.documentElement.scrollTop : 
                                document.body.scrollTop); 
    else return 0;
},

followMouse: function ( event ) {
    var tooltip = Controls._tooltip.style;
    var offX = 15, offY = 15;

    tooltip.left = (parseInt(Controls.mouseX(event))+offX) + 'px';
    tooltip.top = (parseInt(Controls.mouseY(event))+offY) + 'px';
}       
};

Controls.init();
```

EDIT:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/SyJsF/2/

Now the tooltip will follow the mouse.

mouseX() and mouseY() will return the current [x,y] mouse coords. And the follow listener is made with the 'mousemove' event that is attached after the tooltip is created.

Oh, and yeah, I changed the image. Now everyone can be happy....

Comment: ... that [logo](http://inspiredtalents.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/javascript.png) has little to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Javascript to do this:

- Have a tooltip container ready in the dom
- on hover, grab the file href and make a new image tag inside of the tooltip container.

Just make sure to not specify the image dimensions in the tag, or if you do, display the fullsize dimensions not 50x50.

Comment: @keyCrumbs, where is your code example that demonstrates the functionality described by Shan? We're happy to help debug, but where is your starting point aside from the `img` tag?

Comment: you have provided no existing code, so i assume you have none. You provide no desired language, so i assumed what i knew best/probably most people will give you a JS solution. You also didn't say you wanted a code example. I basically assumed you wanted to know the logic. I also have no clue if you are capable of doing anything in javascript.

Comment: lol ok man... i was pretty much just saying. Give more info in your posts and you wont have to go around the comments correcting and clearing things with people...